# Having a problem with selecting data from a column depending on whether another column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to only select the insurance names whose insurance codes are not null from the insuranceCompanies table.

I've tried using this case stmt, but I'm getting a bunch of errors.

```
SELECT     a.Accession, p.ptLastName AS LastName, p.ptFirstName AS 
FirstName, a.ClientCode, c.ClientName, a.PhysicianCode, phs.FullName AS PhysicianName, 
                      p.ptDateOfBirth AS DOB, p.ptSex AS Sex, a.CollectionDate, a.ReceiveDate AS servicedate, 

                      CASE 
                        WHEN ins.InsuranceCode IS NOT NULL THEN ins.[NAME] AS InsuranceName
                        ELSE NULL
                        END AS 'InsuranceName'

FROM         tblAccessions AS a WITH (nolock) INNER JOIN
                      tblPatient AS p WITH (nolock) ON a.PatientID = p.PatientId INNER JOIN
                      tblInsuranceCompanies AS ins WITH (nolock) on CASE WHEN isnull(a.CurrentBillTo, 'Primary') = 'Secondary' THEN  p.SecondaryInsuredID  ELSE  p.PrimaryInsuranceID  END  = ins.InsuranceCode INNER JOIN
                      tblClients AS c WITH (nolock) ON a.ClientCode = c.ClientCode INNER JOIN
                      tblPhysicians AS phs WITH (nolock) ON a.PhysicianCode = phs.PhysicianCode INNER JOIN
                      vAccessionProgress ON a.Accession = vAccessionProgress.Accession LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblAccessionNotes AS an WITH (nolock) ON a.Accession = an.Accession
WHERE     (a.Accession LIKE ISNULL(@Accession, a.Accession))
GROUP BY a.Accession, p.ptLastName, p.ptFirstName, a.ClientCode, c.ClientName, a.PhysicianCode, phs.FullName, p.ptDateOfBirth, p.ptSex, a.CollectionDate, a.ReceiveDate, 
                      vAccessionProgress.Progress, phs.SeriesName, ins.[Name]
```

Here's the error message that I receive.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetAccessionsByParam, Line 25 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I would expect a valid query to have a `FROM` clause.  And one that intends to do filtering to also have a `WHERE`.

Comment: Remove `AS InsuranceName` from `WHEN ins.InsuranceCode IS NOT NULL THEN ins.[NAME] AS InsuranceName`

Comment: The column alias goes after the `CASE ... END` statement. You have it inside the `CASE` statement as @forpas said above.

Comment: `coalese()` will replace your longer expression. Only alias the entire result after `end` and don't wrap the name in single quotes. Use`where ins.InsuranceCode is not null` to actually eliminate those rows.

Comment: I believe, and I'll get corrected if I'm wrong, but `a.Accession LIKE ISNULL(@Accession, a.Accession)` is the same as `a.Accession = ISNULL(@Accession, a.Accession)` because you don't have any wildcard.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - Here is your obligatory correction. The variable `@Accession` could have a patterned string in it, e.g. 'ABC%'

Comment: Slight detour....the NOLOCK hint has a lot of baggage with it that most people don't understand. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: @LaughingVergil, correct!  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
THEN ins.[NAME] AS InsuranceName
```

by removing `AS InsuranceName`.  The alias can not be in the middle of the `CASE` statement.  It must be at the end (which you already have)

Comment: I took out the alias since someone pointed out I already did have it at the end. 
    WHEN ins.InsuranceCode IS NOT NULL THEN ins.[NAME]

I'm getting this error now though:
'tblInsuranceCompanies.InsuranceCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add InsuranceCode to your GroupBy.  The other option is to aggregate it, but I seriously doubt you want to do that.  Insurance Code doesn't sound like a value you'd aggregate.